# What's a good way to "weight" the importance of item/user features in LightFM?

Tags: lightfm

I have been using LightFM in an e-commerce application with a decent amount success. Thanks for this really cool package!

I'm in the process of optimizing the recommendation outputs. Because of specific business domain considerations, certain features are "more important" and have less leeway in terms of variability than others, like "price" (i.e. certain recommended items need to be in a soft price range).

Is there also a way for LightFM to weight this feature MORE than the others?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you find a solution by now?

Comment: Yes, you can always weigh your item-features differently. Ideally for equi-important features, we use l1-normalization to distribute weights evenly. How are you currently building/weighing your item-features matrix?